# OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration white screen

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

After starting the migration (5 team projects, both source code and work items), the interface changes to a white box with an hourglass cursor when I mouse over it.  I let it sit for about an hour, and there was no change.  Clicking on the white UI gives a standard Windows "application not responding" dialog.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you send us logs to ovsmu@opshub.com, logs location <OpsHub Installation>/logs, this will help us to provide proper answer for this question.

Comment: I let it run overnight, and it did eventually start.  I see, though, that the time it will take is on the order of 9 days.  The work items are being created at a rate of about 1 per second or so.  Is this normal?

Comment: No this is not usual , if you can send logs then we will analyze where time is taking more and help you in improving performance.